# Delete array values in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a simple question, if I have an array of strings in python: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] is there a way that I can compare another string and if it exists in the array delete that value and everything after it? I'm new to python and I'm not too familiar with the syntax but pseudocode:

```
s = 'b'
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

if b exists in array
    remove b and elements after
```

so the new array would simply be ['a']. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives:

```
from itertools import takewhile
array = takewhile(lambda x: x != "b", array)
# then if array must be a list (we can already iterate through it)
array = list(array)
```

or

```
if "b" in array:
    del array[array.index("b"):]
```

or

```
try:
    del array[array.index("b"):]
except ValueError:
    # "b" was not in array
    pass
```

Comment: @Elazar POITROAE (premature optimization is the root of all evil)! I would say this `del` is more readable than assigning to an empty list, also it works for iterables that aren't lists.

Comment: I was just about to write that the last version is the best suggested here :) . (And the `del` really introduce no binding in this case, so I'll remove my answer).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Accepted answer due to multiple suggestions :)

Answer (score 7):

```
s = 'b'
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

if s in array:
    del array[array.index(s):]
```